# JavaScript :- remove and add element

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="div-02">Here is div-02</div>
var el = document.getElementById('div-02');
el.remove(); // Removes the div with the 'div-02' id

setTimeout(() => {
el.add?... },5000)
```

I want to remove the element for 5 seconds and make it same as it was previously( before removing it).

Comment: maybe try `display: none`

Comment: Just asking for clarification, you want to remove it for 5 seconds and then restore it? If so you can just hide and show

Comment: Hi, can you use jquery or pure js?

Comment: I am working on ANgular project so probably pure js but hide and show solved my problem I was going in wrong direction

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can take the element in a temporary variable so that you can append that after the time ends:

```js
var temp = document.getElementById('div-02');
var el = document.getElementById('div-02');
el.remove(); // Removes the div with the 'div-02' id
setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.append(temp); 
},5000)
```

```html
<div id="div-02">Here is div-02</div>
```

But the ideal solution would be hide/show using the style property of the element:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('div-02');
el.style.display = 'none';
setTimeout(() => {
  el.style.display = 'block';
},5000)
```

```html
<div id="div-02">Here is div-02</div>
```